# Put in an array what I have selected

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, foreach

If I check 2 fruits from the various options I have, for example banana and apple chek return this

```
foreach( $checkboxes as $check ) {
    echo $check;  print bananaapple
}
```

I need that before saving a database it must be like this: `banana,apple` array.

```
global $wpdb; 
$wpdb->insert('data',array( 
  'fruit' => $check ));
```

If I put it like this it shows me only the last check marked, in this case it shows apple in DB.

Comment: _.. banana,apple.._ Stop here, don't store delimiter separated lists

Answer (score 0):

use implode

```
$checkboxes = ['banana', 'apple'];
echo implode(',', $checkboxes); // returns banana,apple
```